# Geometry Conjecture, Interpretation.

Tags: geometry

I've been participating in a message group on geometry and the following conjecture has been presented.  I am only trying to understand it fully.  First the conjecture is the following:

**"ABC is a triangle with circumcenter O.  A1B1C1 is the cevian triangle of O with respect to ABC. A2B2C2 is cevian triangle of O with respect to A1B1C1.
AnBnCn is cevian triangle of O with respect to A(n-1)B(n-1)C(n-1).
I conjecture that when n tends to infinity then sequence centroid of triangles AnBnCn tends to O.  Is it true?"**

It is the last part regarding "sequence centroid" that I am failing to understand.  If the centroid is the concurrency point of the medians, then what is meant by "sequence centroid"? Does it mean to ask whether the successive centroid points of the triangles AnBnCn go towards the circumcenter O, and become synonymous with it?  That would be an interesting thing to prove, perhaps, if that is in fact the meaning.  As n approaches infinity the triangles become infinitely small it would seem.  I suppose the question is whether such a succession of triangles condenses to the point O. Is this the correct way to interpret this question?